# Leitura de txt em Assembly i8086

Tags: arquivo, assembly, txt, 8086

Tenho o seguinte código para ler arquivo txt:

```
; um programa que demonstra a criação de um arquivo e a
; leitura do mesmo

.model small
.stack
.code 

start:

mov ax,@data        ; endereço de base do segmento de dados
mov ds,ax       ; é colocado em ds

mov dx,OFFSET FileName  ; coloca o endereço do nome do arquivo em dx
mov al,2        ; modo de acesso - leitura e escrita
mov ah,3Dh      ; função 3Dh - abre um arquivo
int 21h         ; chama serviço do DOS

mov Handle,ax       ; guarda o manipulador do arquivo para mais tarde
jc ErrorOpening     ; desvia se carry flag estiver ligada - erro!

mov dx,offset Buffer    ; endereço do buffer em dx
mov bx,Handle       ; manipulador em bx
mov cx,100      ; quantidade de bytes a serem lidos
mov ah,3Fh      ; função 3Fh - leitura de arquivo
int 21h         ; chama serviço do DOS

jc ErrorReading     ; desvia se carry flag estiver ligada - erro!

mov bx,Handle       ; coloca manipulador do arquivo em bx
mov ah,3Eh      ; função 3Eh - fechar um arquivo
int 21h         ; chama serviço do DOS

mov cx,100      ; comprimento da string
mov si,OFFSET Buffer    ; DS:SI - endereço da string
xor bh,bh       ; página de vídeo - 0
mov ah,0Eh      ; função 0Eh - escrever caracter

NextChar:

lodsb           ; AL = próximo caracter da string
int 10h         ; chama serviço da BIOS
loop NextChar

mov ax,4C00h        ; termina programa
int 21h 

ErrorOpening:

mov dx,offset OpenError ; exibe um erro
mov ah,09h      ; usando a função 09h
int 21h         ; chama serviço do DOS
mov ax,4C01h        ; termina programa com um errorlevel =1 
int 21h 

ErrorReading:
mov dx,offset ReadError ; exibe um erro
mov ah,09h      ; usando a função 09h
int 21h         ; chama serviço do DOS
mov ax,4C02h        ; termina programa com um errorlevel =2
int 21h

.data
Handle DW ?             ; para guardar o manipulador do arquivo
FileName DB "C:\test.txt",0     ; arquivo a ser aberto
OpenError DB "Ocorreu um erro(abrindo)!$"
ReadError DB "Ocorreu um erro(lendo)!$"
Buffer DB 100 dup (?)   ; buffer para armazenar dados

END start
```

Teria como fazer para ler ate o final do arquivo sem ter que informar a quantidade de bytes a serem lidos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ler o arquivo sem especificar o tamanho, você precisa efetuar a leitura até detectar o final do arquivo.

Um exemplo de como alterar o programa para ler arquivos maiores sem especificar o tamanho:

Na rotina de leitura do arquivo, modificar para ler um bloco de tamanho fixo e alterar o endereço do buffer conforme os blocos de texto forem lidos. Para detectar o final do arquivo, compare a quantidade de bytes lidos com a quantidade solicitada e termine se for menor ([INT 21,3F](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21-3f.html)):

```
        ...
        mov dx,offset Buffer    ; endereço do buffer em dx

    LerBloco:                   ; início da leitura do bloco

        mov bx,Handle           ; manipulador em bx
        mov cx,512              ; quantidade de bytes a serem lidos
        mov ah,3Fh              ; função 3Fh - leitura de arquivo
        int 21h                 ; chama serviço do DOS

        jc ErrorReading         ; desvia se carry flag estiver ligada - erro!

        add [BytesLidos], cx    ; adiciona a quantidade de bytes lidos
        cmp ax, cx              ; compara quantos bytes foram lidos com a quantidade solicitada na função            
        jb  Continuar           ; sair da leitura, caso seja menor (final do arquivo encontrado!)

        add dx,512              ; avança o buffer de leitura
        cmp dx, FimBuffer       ; verifica se chegou no final do buffer
        jae Continuar           ; se dx for maior ou igual ao final, sair da leitura
        jmp LerBloco

    Continuar:

        mov bx,Handle           ; coloca manipulador do arquivo em bx
        mov ah,3Eh              ; função 3Eh - fechar um arquivo
        int 21h                 ; chama serviço do DOS

        mov cx,[BytesLidos]     ; comprimento da string (Ler o valor da variável BytesLidos)
        mov si,OFFSET Buffer    ; DS:SI - endereço da string
        xor bh,bh               ; página de vídeo - 0
        mov ah,0Eh              ; função 0Eh - escrever caracter
        ...
```

Na área de dados, definir as variáveis *BytesLidos*, *FimBuffer* e aumentar o tamanho do buffer:

```
    .data
    BytesLidos  DW 0                ; Bytes lidos do arquivo
    Buffer      DB 4096 dup (?)     ; buffer para armazenar dados
    FimBuffer   DW $-Buffer         ; Endereço do fim do buffer
```

Com essas alterações, o programa consegue ler um arquivo de até 4096 bytes (tamanho máximo do buffer) sem precisar especificar previamente o tamanho a ser lido.

Caso você precise ler arquivos maiores, é possível criar uma lógica parecida com essa para ler um bloco, imprimir e reiniciar o buffer, ler o próximo, imprimir e reiniciar o buffer, e assim por diante.

Comment: Valeu, ajudou bastante! Outra coisa, eu conseguiria através desse código ler linha por linha ao invés de ler por blocos?

Comment: @SamuelHenrique Não. O DOS não possui função para leitura de linhas. Você precisaria implementar a lógica para procurar o caracter `'\r'` (LF) e descobrir onde fica o final de cada linha dentro do buffer.

Comment: Certo, eu tenho um trabalho para fazer que preciso manipular as linhas de um txt sendo que cada linha representa dados de um sensor. Seria melhor entao ler o arquivo dessa maneira e depois manipular pelo buffer?

Comment: Se o arquivo for pequeno (até o tamanho do buffer), sim. Você pode ler o arquivo inteiro para o buffer e depois processar. Se ele for grande, é melhor processar em partes, como eu expliquei na resposta

Comment: Certo, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: De nada! Se a resposta foi útil, por favor, marque-a como aceita: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079

Comment: Mais uma dúvida: no programa serão feitas as leituras de 4 arquivos, sendo que 3 necessitam ir para a memória e o outro o professor disse que não deve ir, posso manter-lo em algum outro local de armazenamento ou não há essa possibilidade? Pois se não houver, acredito que terei que ler os dados e já tratá-los.

Comment: Se ele não pode ir para a memória (buffer), a única saída provável é ler e já processar.

Comment: OK, mas como ficaria esse código? Daria para substituir o buffer por um registrador ou algo assim?

Comment: Você pode fazer a leitura de 1 byte e já processar, mas de qualquer forma, a leitura desse byte vai para uma posição de memória. Tente implementar a leitura com 1 byte e, caso dê problema, faça uma nova pergunta aqui.

Comment: A leitura do arquivo que não deve ficar na memória estou fazendo uma linha por vez mas ao ler uma linha completa, preciso esvaziar o buffer e fazer com que a leitura da próxima fique a partir do início do buffer. Tentei limpar o buffer de várias maneiras mas não obtive sucesso. Conhece alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Comment: Para reiniciar o buffer, é só carregar o registrador `dx` com o endereço `offset Buffer` novamente. De qualquer forma, você precisa alterar a lógica do programa, pois o DOS não possui o conceito de "linha" e a leitura só pode ocorrer para a memória, seja ela de 1 byte ou de 512 bytes (ou qualquer tamanho), portanto, a lógica do programa será bem diferente.